# How to test a Controller and Model in a JSF Project with jUnit?

Tags: jsf, junit, model, controller, ejb

i don't know exactly how to write tests for these following Classes especially for the Controller and Model. Is it to possible to test with jUnit ?
I heard from Selenium but first i would test with jUnit. Thanks for ur help and best regards.

Controller.class:

```js
import factory.InfoMessageFactory;
import entity.Product;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import model.ProductModel;
import project.Konstanten;

@Named(value = "ProductController")
@SessionScoped
public class ProductController implements Serializable {
   
    private Product product;
    
    @Inject
    private ProductModel model;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.product = new Product();
    }
    
   
    public String addProduct() {
       this.model.newProduct(this.product);
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProdukt(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
    
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return this.model.getProducts();
    }
}
```

Model.class

```js
package model;

import ejb.DB;
import entity.Product;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@Dependent
public class ProductModel implements Serializable{
    
    @Inject
    private DB db;
    
    public boolean addProduct(Product p){
        try{
            db.persist(p);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Blablabla");
            return false;                
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And DB.class

```js
@Stateless
public class DB {

    @Inject
    @RealClass
    private EntityManager em;
    
    public void persist(Object object) {
        em.persist(object);
    }
```

Comment: you want to have unit or integration tests?

Comment: just unit tests

Comment: Use arquillian with jsfunit. Way easier since you use a real container and do not need to mock everything you do not want/need to mock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `ProductController`, there is really not much to test.. unless there is more logic that you did not post.

For testing the `ProductModel`, or any service-like class having the `DB` dependency i would suggest adding a project dependency to one of the mocking frameworks (i suggest Mockito as it is the most mature of them all).

For the `addProducts` method you could end up with following tests:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

public class ProductModelTest{

@Mock
private DB dbMock;

@InjectMocks
private ProdcutModel = new ProductModel();

@Before
public void init(){
   MockitoAnnotations.iniMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void shouldReturnTrue_whenEntityPersisted(){
    doNothing().when(dbMock).persist(any(Product.class));

    boolean result = productModel.addProduct(new Product());

    assertTrue(result);
}

@Test
    public void shouldReturnFalse_whenEntityPersisted(){
        doThrow(RuntimeException.class).when(dbMock).persist(any(Product.class));

        boolean result = productModel.addProduct(new Product());

        assertFalse(result);
}
}
```

Regarding the DB-like repository classes.. i normally do not unit-test them. IF so i run integration tests on them.